# Retrieving data from composite table using HQL

Tags: .net, nhibernate, hql, nhibernate-criteria

Using NHibernate for .NET I have 3 tables. One is `CourseType`, the other is `Contact` and the last being a composite called `CourseType_Contact` the composite table looks like this...

```
CourseTypeID Guid, ContactID Guid
```

I am attempting to use HQL to write a query that will retrieve all the `Contacts` for a specific coursetype but I'm lost as to how to do this in HQL.

In SQL my query would look like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE ContactID IN(
SELECT ContactID FROM CourseType_Contact WHERE CourseTypeID = @CourseTypeID)
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have a `Contacts` property on your class `CourseType`?

Comment: Yes but in this case I don't want to retrieve the actual CourseType I just want the associations.

Answer (score 0):

Long time not using HQL, but I think you could do

```
SELECT co FROM CourseType ct 
JOIN   ct.Contacts co
WHERE  ct.CourseTypeId = :Id
```